# Animate UIView to snap to a set position

Tags: ios, uiview, uianimation

I am trying to animate my view when dragging is released, but I can't seem to achieve a clean effect...it tends to jump all the way to the top of the screen and then it animates from the top to the desired position.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    if (scrollView == self.outerScrollView) {
        CGPoint translation = [scrollView.panGestureRecognizer translationInView:scrollView];
        if (translation.y < 0) {
            CGRect frame = self.tabBarController.view.bounds;
            frame.origin.y = 100;
            [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
                self.tabBarController.view.center = self.tabBarController.view.frame = frame;
            }];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify the option `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState`, so you also need to switch to the block animation method `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:` - that way it should not jump to the top of the screen before beginning the animation you want.